# python Tkinter textpad event binding for huge number of entry...crashes GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, event-binding

I am trying to do a GUI in Tkinter and i have 1 million entries into textpad. So am binding a function to each entry that should be called upon mouse click. But as the entries are inserted to textpad and bind to function, after 0.6 million entries the GUI starts to freeze( i am curently using python-SQL to reduce memory usage on RAM).

```
traces=sql_database.debug_read(id_count)    #reading data from SQL
x1=0     #tag number for binding
for i in range(len(traces)): 
    Id,t_s,tra_id,t_d=traces[i]    #splitting data to be printed
    m,g,s_t=dict2[tra_id]          #checking data with a dictionary 
    filtered_data=t_s+tra_id+t_d
    data_to_print=str(t_s)+'\t '+m+'\t '+g+'\t '+s_t
    textPad.insert('end',data_to_print,x1)
    if i%20000==0: 
          mainWindow.update() 
          textPad.see(END)
    textPad.tag_bind(x1,'<1>'(lambda e,x1=x1:decoder_fun(x1,t_d)))
    x1=x1+1
```

without  event  binding the GUI is working properly..
The cpu usage and RAM usage is medium, with binding..

Comment: Your GUI has 1 million entries ???!!! I do not know any screen which can hold them or a human who can interact with them.

Comment: the textpad have scroll button to see  whole entries.....and i need to interact with them.

Comment: Why are you making a million bindings rather than just one binding? The bound function is given enough information to know where you clicked. Have you tried with just a single binding? And why are you using a Text widget? It seems like a listbox makes more sense.

Comment: If i use a single binding , the decoder function will be acting on whole entries, i need to decode individual entries using another function upon click on each one... i will try using listbox..thx

Comment: you can still have a single binding, and then figure out which tagged item was clicked on. It would really help if you created a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that didn't require your actual dataset. For example, a simple loop that generates fake but representative data would be useful.

Comment: """you can still have a single binding, and then figure out which tagged item was clicked on""
can you gave me any reference links to this method, i think this will help me to solve my problem.......

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using textpad , i used listbox, which provies good method to get each enties in the listbox. In listbox event we can get the index on which the mouse click occurred, with that index i am able to interact (call function ) to individual entries in the listbox. And i just need only one single bind for the whole listbox entries

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

def callback(event):
    index=w.curselection()
    #print index
    print w.get(index)


root=Tkinter.Tk()
scrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
w=Tkinter.Listbox(root)
w.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=w.yview)
for i in range(20):
    w.insert(i,i)
w.pack()
def ons():
    w.delete(1,END)
w.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',callback)
b=Tkinter.Button(root,command=ons)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The curselection() will give the index on which mouse click occurred. And get(index) will give the entries on listbox of that index number.
we have to use the  "ListboxSelect" bind to use these methods for the mouse click event.
more options are in this link:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_listbox.htm